# implement Horner's scheme in java for two variable polynomials

Tags: java, math, geometry

I have already understood the Horner's scheme for one variable polynomials like (2x^3+x+1) but I have not found a clear explenation for the two variable polynomials like (2x^6+3y+9) and i want to create a program in java to calcualte the scheme for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use that `A[x,Y] = A[x][Y]`. In other words, consider your polynomials in `x` and `Y` with coefficients in some set `A` as polynomials in `Y`, whose coefficients are in turn polynomials, this time in `A[x]`. For example, rewrite

```
x^3+x^2Y+xY^2+xY+x^2+x+Y^3+Y^2+Y+1
```

as

```
Y^3 + (x+1)Y^2 + (x^2+x+1)Y + (x^3+x^2+x+1)
```

and then apply Horn first in `A[x][Y]` using it again for every one of the coefficients `1`, `x+1`, `xˆ2+x+1`and `x^3+x^2+x+1` in `A[x]`.

Note that this will require sorting first the monomials according to their `Y`-degree and after grouping the coefficients, sorting their monomials according to the `x`-degree.

Answer (score 0):

For two variables you could separate the two and apply the rule to each group:

```
x^3+x^2y+xy^2+xy+x^2+x+1+y^3+y^2+y+1=

=[1+x(1+y+y^2+x(1+y+x))+]+[1+y(1+y(1+y))]
```

So the algorithm would be:

- Put x and xy terms in one group
- treat y as a constant and apply
- put y-only terms in another
- apply